# Is it ever ok to change you question to make one of the answers fit better

Tags: support

The question I asked was [How do I configure WinMerge as the compare and merge tool for TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-winmerge-as-the-compare-and-merge-tool-for-tfs), which I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-winmerge-as-the-compare-and-merge-tool-for-tfs/1313946#1313946) myself. However, I did not mark it as the accepted answer in case someone else provided a better answer.

[TehOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21932/tehone) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313908/how-do-i-configure-winmerge-as-the-compare-and-merge-tool-for-tfs/1313961#1313961) the question with a [link to an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx) that shows you how to configure TFS to work with many merge tools. I'd like to mark that as the accept answer and change my question to "How do I configure TFS to work with various merge tools?" Would this be considered acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!**

I'll occasionally do this when closing a newer question as a duplicate, to help future searchers better find a good (but originally overly-specific) question with good (general-purpose) answers. If it's actually *your question*, then by all means generalize it if you have an answer that answers the more general case!

Comment: Ok I changed the question.